# Any language - Declare any variable size

Tags: variables, memory, int

I know the types serve to define as such a variable occupies in memory. So I could declare a variable of size I wanted? For example, suppose my variable values ​​will use 0-3. I do not know as an `int` occupies in python, but we assume that is `8 bytes`. I do not need all that to store up to the `number 3`. Could do the same using `2 bits.` You can do this in python or any other language? But it could also declare a variable `1-bit, 7-bit, 54 bit`, the size I wanted?

Comment: If you're THIS worried about memory allocation, DO NOT USE AN INTERPRETED LANGUAGE like Python. We need to see the forest from the trees on this one

Comment: Is it the memory size of the variable that you are interested in or the do you want to limit the range of values that users can store in your variable?

Comment: @That1Guy He's trying to ask what language best lets him optimize memory. He wants a variable whose values will never exceed `4`, but it is stored in 8 bytes rather than 2 bits. I can edit for clarity.

Comment: Exact @AdamSmith. Sorry not clear. can edit

Answer (score 0):

#### For Python

You do not know how much space the variable takes.  If you are concerned with space, write it in C.  You can use a byte and other constructs, but conversion between the lose anything you save in space.

To find out the largest int supported, use `sys.maxint`.

#### In General

If you are NOT referring to Python, then we can take C for example.  There are many different types for space utilization.

```
unsigned char - 1 byte
small int - 2 byte
int - 4 bytes
long - 8 bytes
```

But storing it in 2 bits?  If you are decrementing and incrementing, you might lose in complexity what you gain in space.

Are you going to pack other variables in the same byte to fill it up?
Are you sure you don't corrupt those values with your bit math?

For many reasons, it makes sense to only go down to the byte level for something like this.

Comment: OP just changed this question to remove references to Python.

Comment: @AdamSmith, he still refers to Python in his question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham so he does. He'd removed the [tag:python] tag and the word Python from the title.